# rails 3 model name conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, conflict

i have a model called Job. In ruby core there is a module Benchmark and class within it Job.

That's make the conflict when i try to call Job.all.

Is there any possible and safe solution to resolve this without to rename my model?

Big thanks

Comment: Did you try `::Job.all`?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming your model is the safest way, but you can try with namespaces:

```
module MyModule
   class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.Yes, i try with ::Job.all, same thing. I know that i can put namespace to my model, but that also require a lot of refactoring....I suppose i'm stack within it...